# How to Combine CURL with Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I'm attempting to send a CURL request and then use '`simple_html_dom`' class to
find the html elements I want. (Parsing) — in this case I send a CURL request to 'google.com' and then use '`simple_html_dom`' class to select all of the links of the page. (or any other HTML tags.)

**The problem:**
I don't know how to combine CURL with the '`simple_html_dom`' class.

Here is my code:

**Curl Request:**

```
function GetPage($url){ 
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
      $userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
      $str = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);

        return $str;
    }
        $output = GetPage('http://www.google.com/');
```

**How I attempt to use '`simple_html_dom`' class:**

```
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load($output, true, false);
        $links = $html->find('a');          
        foreach ($links as $link){
            echo $link.'</br>';
        }
```

When I load my file, it shows **no** errors, but it doesn't show the links I selected either.

**Note:**
I've looked through this website to make sure this question hasn't been answered,but it actually was answered a couple of times, but it still didn't solve it.

Comment: Have you done some sanity tests, like echoing out $output to make sure the HTML is fetched correctly?

Comment: @nathan show us the curl  response.

Comment: Extrakun,Yes I did: It printed out the whole page.

Comment: Edit: Some magical thing happened and when I refreshed the page it did show all of the links of the page! I didn't change anything... any explanation?

Comment: You're faking a googlebot UA to access google? That seems like something they would be quick to catch.